# How to disable smooth scrolling on the WinRT side?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1-preview

Is there any way to disable smooth scrolling for the Start screen and in Windows Store Apps?

The scroll wheel on my mouse is of the free-spinning type, where it doesn't have those stopping notches. Smooth scrolling doesn't play well with it at all.

The behavior is difficult to describe, but it's very jerky and it usually waits for the wheel to decelerate before it starts to scroll, and it can continue scrolling even after the wheel is stopped.

I'm sure the issue is smooth scrolling as there was identical behavior in IE11, but disabling the option is simple there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem no longer exists (Windows 8.1).

Answer (score 0):

Type `scroll` at the Start Screen, and choose one of the listed settings.
That will take you to the Control Panel where you can change the scroll behavior (e.g., changing the number of lines scrolled from 3 to 1, or scrolling a page at a time).

You may also try unchecking **Smooth-scroll list boxes** under System properties | **Advanced system properties** | Performance **Settings...** | **Visual effects** tab.

Answer (score 0):

- This is disable Smooth-scroling Window 8/8.1
  Apply work for Start Screen window 8/8.1, Office 2013 - Word, Exel and any application in Window...

You need disable Visual Effect

1. Right Click My Computer --> Properties
2. Advanced system setting
3. Tag Performance Visual Effect... Click Setting
4. Clear check box Animate controls and elements inside windows